# Error in my Kafka custom partitioner class

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am working on a Kafka Custom partitioner class. Here I am trying to push the data into separate partitions.
My Kafka producer class:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;

import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;

public class KafkaCustomPartitioner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long events = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
        int  blocks = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        Random  rnd = new Random();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("serializer.class","kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        props.put("key.serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        props.put("partitioner.class","com.kafka.partdecider.CustomPartitioner");
        props.put("producer.type", "sync");
        props.put("request.required.acks","1");

        ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
        Producer producer = new Producer(config);

        for(int nBlocks=0; nBlocks<blocks; nBlocks++) {
            for(long nEvents=0; nEvents<events; nEvents++) {
                long runTime = new Date().getTime();
                String msg   = runTime + ": " + (50+nBlocks) + ": " + nEvents + ": " + rnd;
                KeyedMessage<String, String> data = new KeyedMessage<String, String>("CustPartTopic",String.valueOf(nBlocks),msg);
                producer.send(data);
            }
        }
        producer.close();
    }
}
```

Customer Partitioner Class:

```
import kafka.producer.Partitioner;

public class CustomPartitioner implements Partitioner {

    public int partition(Object key, int arg1) {
        String receivingkey = (String) key;
        long id = Long.parseLong(receivingkey);
        return (int) (id%arg1);
    }
}
```

The project's arguments section has the values: 3 2
I am getting "ArrayOutOfBoundsException" at this line if I run the class:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.kafka.custompartitioner.KafkaCustomPartitioner.main(KafkaCustomPartitioner.java:13)
```

The error is shown at the line:`long events = Long.parseLong(args[0]);`
But I don't understand why is that line giving the error. 
Could anyone let me know how can I fix this ?

Comment: Just asking, are you working with Kafka version before Kafka 0.8.2 ? You are using very old API.

Comment: I am using the version 0.10 (kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0). 
Can you tell me what are the corrections I need to make for the latest version ? This is the dependency in my pom.xml
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
     <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
     <version>0.9.0.0</version>
 </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, the API are quite different :

```
package mypackage.io;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class KafkaCustomPartitioner {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    long events = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
    int  blocks = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    Random rnd = new Random();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, "mypackage.io.CustomPartitioner");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "1");

    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);

    for(int nBlocks=0; nBlocks<blocks; nBlocks++) {

        for(long nEvents=0; nEvents<events; nEvents++) {

            long runTime = new Date().getTime();
            String msg   = runTime + ": " + (50+nBlocks) + ": " + nEvents + ": " + rnd;
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("CustPartTopic", String.valueOf(nBlocks), msg)).get();
        }
    }
    producer.close();
    }
 }
```

then the custom partitioner

```
package mypackage.io;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Partitioner;
import org.apache.kafka.common.Cluster;

import java.util.Map;

public class CustomPartitioner implements Partitioner {

public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {

    String receivingkey = (String) key;
    long id = Long.parseLong(receivingkey);
    int numPartitions = cluster.availablePartitionsForTopic(topic).size();
    return (int) (id % numPartitions);
}

public void close() {

}

public void configure(Map<String, ?> map) {

}
}
```

Comment: It is working now. And where do we pass the number of partitions value here ?

Comment: you don't pass it. You created the topic specifying the number of partitions it's made. Then the Cluster object is used for retrieving number of partitions for that topic.

Comment: My bad. I meant where do we specify the parameter for number of partitions ? 
That will end my program requirement.

Comment: in the new Partitioner interface you don't have this parameter anymore, for this reason I'm using : cluster.availablePartitionsForTopic(topic).size();

Comment: Okay. So we don't need to tell the program(anywhere in the code) to create particular number of partitions and in that case will the program decide it dynamically ?

Comment: In Kafka you create the topic with the related number of partitions upfront before running your application which will send/receive messages. More information on documentation here : https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart_createtopic